# Is $\mathbb{E}\left(\left| X \right| \right) < \infty$ if and only if $\mathbb{E}\left(X^2\right) < \infty$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Given a random variable, $X$, in a probability space, $(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$, do we have that $\mathbb{E}\left(\left| X \right| \right) < \infty$ if and only if $\mathbb{E}\left(X^2\right) < \infty$?

If not, does one imply the other?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you come up with such a statement?

Comment: No and yes.  What have you tried?

Comment: Hint. Think about the harmonic series and the sum of the reciprocals of the squares.

Comment: I am doing a past exam, and in a question I am given a sequence of random vairables satisfying the latter condition but I need to show that the sequence of random variables is a martingale, and hence that it satisfies the former condition. @K

Comment: $L^p \subset L^q\text{ if } 1 \le q \le p$.

Comment: @Henry I have only intuitively thought about it; I suspect it is trivial, but I can't form a concrete argument.

Comment: consider a t distribution with 2 degree of freedom. the mean is zero but the variance, that is, $EX^2$, does not exist. thus the only if direction cannot hold true. conversely, applying cauchy schwartz inequality $EX^2 \leq (E|X|)^2(E|X|)^2$. if $E|X|$ is finite so is $EX^2$

Comment: Try $X(\omega) = {1 \over \sqrt{ \omega}}$ on $(0,1)$. Note that $EX$ is finite, $EX^2$ is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the probability distribution given by

$f(x) = c \frac{1}{1 + |x|^3}$

where $c$ is the positive constant that normalises $f$.

We see that $\mathbb{E}(|X|) < \infty$ but $\mathbb{E}(|X|^2) = \infty$.

However, suppose $\mathbb{E}(X^2) < \infty$. Since $|x| \leq x^2 + 1$ for all $x$, we must have $\mathbb{E}(|X|) \leq \mathbb{E}(X^2 + 1) = 1 + \mathbb{E}(X^2)$. Thus, if $\mathbb{E}(X^2) < \infty$, we must have $\mathbb{E}(|X|) < \infty$.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. When I attempted arguing that $\mathbb{E}(X^2) < \infty$ $\implies$ $\mathbb{E}(|X|) < \infty$, I also wanted to do it via an inequality between $\left| x \right|$ and $x^2$, but thought it just fell apart for $x < 1$, so I scrapped that path. The fact that $|x| \leq x^2 + 1$ is a nice little trick I will use in the future!